# System stops recognizing headphones

Tags: sound, headphones

I am running Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS on a Lenovo Legion Y540. The system recognizes the headphones after power-up. When I need a break, I unplug the headphones. Sometimes, when I plug them back in, I only get silence. If I unplug the headphones, play the video for a second, then plug the headphones back in, I get sound through the headphones again. But, more often, the system stops recognizing the headphones altogether. Sound comes through the speaker even with the headphones plugged in. The system menu shows a speaker near the volume slider, and no headphone symbol. When I reboot, the headphones work again.
Does anyone know what's going on, and whether there's a way to handle this without a reboot?
I have no error log to post, because there is none given.

Comment: Your headphones are connected via audio jack I suppose from reading the question. Did you try a different set of headphones, in order to rule out if your default ones used causes the issue?

Comment: Yes,, I did. I still haven't tracked down the problem. I was wondering at first if it had something to do with the NVIDIA chip. An lshw seems to indicate two audio devices, one of them by intel and one by NVIDIA. So, I wondered if it was a driver bug. A restart of gdm3 doesn't fix it, though, that still requires a hard restart of the machine.

Comment: I've noticed a lot of clicking and static when I plug the headphones into the jack. I'm wondering if it's really a static electricity issue. (I've seen some posts by Lenovo users with headphones not working at all needing their motherboard replaced.) I've tried touching the computer above the jack with hand while plugging it in with the the other, and I've had success. But I haven't had a chance to do it often enough to call it a solution.

Comment: I currently use a Lenovo Z50-70, running Ubuntu. The laptops internal speakers stopped working after a while, but my headphones still work fine. However the contacts of the audio-jack (ground/left/right) inside the laptop are quite sensitive preassure I noticed, since they retracted into the walls of the round jack-slot. I used a thin metal shim to bend them back towards the center, in order to reestablish contact with the headphones jack. So maybe it is a mechanical problem?

Comment: I don't know if it's a mechanical problem. It's strange that a reboot fixes it. The frustrating part is that when I try to get the problem to happen under controlled circumstances, I can't get it to happen. It only happens when I take a break from a movie to get food, come back, and want to restart the movie before my food gets cold. That's when I have to reboot. It also happens when I get up to use the bathroom and come back and my asthma is acting up. In other words, it happens often, but only in instances when I can't give it my full attention. Arrggghh!

Comment: I was looking into restarting the sound driver. I learned you have to kill pulseaudio first, but then you have to quickly unload the snd_hda_intel driver before pulseaudio respawns. The next time my problem occurs, I'm going to try: killall -9 pulseaudio ; sudo modprobe -r snd_hda_intel ; sleep 1 ; sudo modprobe snd_hda_intel. When the sda_hda_intel module is unloaded, I only see a speaker icon near the volume control in the system menu. When I reload the sda_hda_intel module, I hear a soft "wump" in the headphones, and the headphone symbol reappears next to the volume slider.

Comment: I finally got a chance to try the above, and it didn't work. I also threw in a sudo alsa force-reload. I don't know why, but a hard reboot does the trick. If this problem is actually restricted to Ubuntu or Linux, it's buried deep.

Comment: Sadly I have no idea, what exactly the problem is and how to fix it. Nevertheless, it is very annoying to reboot the system every time! Hopefully you'll find the solution soon!

Comment: "I am running Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS on a Lenovo Legion Y540. The system recognizes the headphones after power-up."  " Sound comes through the speaker even with the headphones plugged in." - I have the same setup and exactly the same problems. Have you found any solution?

Comment: Antonio - I'm still hunting for a solution. I found that I don't actually have to reboot to get the headphones working. Power off/Log out -> Suspend works too. Once I "unsuspend" by hitting the Shift key, the headphones work. I do have to close down anything graphical (web browser, video player, games, etc.) because graphics and sound get "wonky" after a suspend if the application presenting them is left open. It's still a pain, but it's faster than a reboot. I'd really like to know what goes on during a suspend, but no one seems to be able to tell me.

Comment: I'm thinking the problem is with pulseaudio. I found a utility called pavucontrol (which you can install with apt). It allows you to select your sound output device. It will say "Headphones (unplugged)", but you can select it anyway, and the headphones will work fine. It's better than suspending the system and bringing everything down.